# How to apply a function on a backreference?

Tags: python, regex, function, backreference

Say I have strings like the following:

```
old_string = "I love the number 3 so much"
```

I would like to spot the integer numbers (in the example above, there is only one number, `3`), and replace them with a value larger by 1, i.e., the desired result should be

```
new_string = "I love the number 4 so much"
```

In Python, I can use:

```
r = re.compile(r'([0-9])+')
new_string = r.sub(r'\19', s)
```

to append a `9` at the end of the integer numbers matched. However, I would like to apply something more general on `\1`.

If I define a function:

```
def f(i):
    return i + 1
```

How do I apply `f()` on `\1`, so that I can replace the matched strings in `old_string` with something like `f(\1)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to having a replace string, `re.sub` allows you to use a function to do the replacements:

```
>>> import re
>>> old_string = "I love the number 3 so much"
>>> def f(match):
...     return str(int(match.group(1)) + 1)
...
>>> re.sub('([0-9])+', f, old_string)
'I love the number 4 so much'
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of `pattern`. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.